# Joomla and JomSocial Error

Tags: joomla, jomsocial

I'm having problem with a client site.  I'm not good with Joomla (we mostly do Wordpress), but one of my long-time clients asked me to move a site from another developer that never finished it, so I obliged.  The problem is, everything is working great except for the Community page:

http://gettingripped.com/index.php/community

The only errors I'm finding are with the Facebook integration (which they told me the previous dev never finished/fixed).    I'm really confused here...anyone out there have any ideas?  It seems instead of showing the proper titles that Com_community_somethingElseHere is replacing everything.

Thank you guys in advance for your help!

Comment: It would appear that the language file isn't being loaded onto the page. Try to turn on the Joomla debug feature and check if the relevant language file is being included. If not - should be a relatively easy fix to include it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems something is wrong with the **en-GB.com_community.ini** file.

Location: gettingripped.com/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_community.ini

I could not find the file in the above location!!!

Put this file in that folder and it will work!!!

If you can't find the file to put in the folder, create your own and place it there.. how? Well, google for this string as it is (including double quotes) `"en-GB.com_community.ini"`  and open the first couple of results.

Then copy paste the displayed file content into your own ini file (name it en-GB.com_community.ini) and place it in your en-GB folder.

Load the page and it will show up as it should!

Comment: That was it!  Somehow that file got skipped in migration!  Thank you so much!